# Try to install intel cluster studio on centos, but skcript exiting with "binary operator expected"

Tags: centos, bash, intel

I am trying to install intels cluster studio 2016 on my centos 7 system.
When I try to execute the installation skript I get the following error.

install.sh: line 331: [: /tmp/intel.pset hostname.domain.name.bla binary operator expected

What I need to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Script's busted.  Go bug Intel.

Comment: What shell are you using? Try to use bash.